# Hadoop Cluster datanodes go down very frequently

Tags: hadoop

I have a cluster of primary and secondary namenodes along with 9 datanodes.
Many of my Datanodes go down very frequently, could anyone plz suggest me the solution of unstability of my cluster.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) For target-oriented suggestions you will have to describe the situation (much) more elaborately. For a discussion at [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), argue how this pertains to programming.

Comment: Look at the datanode and namenode process  logs